# Como agarrar datos de un input de select para introducirlos en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, html5, bootstrap-4

quisiera saber como obtengo los datos de un input de `<select></select>` para agregar dichos valores a la base de datos,

```
        $form = '<form action="store.php?'. htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).' method="get">';
        $form .='<div class="form-group">';
        $form .= '<label for="quantity">Select You Quantity"'.$_GET['name'].'"</label>';
        $form .= '<select class="form-control-sm" id="quantity" name="quantity">';
        $form .= '<option value="quantity">1</option>';
        $form .= '<option value="quantity">2</option>';
        $form .= '<option value="3">3</option>';
        $form .= '<option value="4">4</option>';
        $form .= '</select>';
        $form .= '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info m-2" value="Add" name="'.$_GET['name'].'">';

        print_r($form);
```

,hice esta semi funcion, pero quiero obtener los valores del select es decir que si le doy a la opcion 1 , 2 , 3 ; obtenga dichos valores para introducirlos a la base de datos

Comment: Puedes serializar el formulario en Javascript y enviar los datos al servidor vía Ajax para inserción. Si sólo te interesa el dato del `select`, igual, por Javascript obtienes el elemento seleccionado y lo envías al servidor por Ajax para insertarlo. No es muy complicado, puedes investigar aquí mismo, hay varios ejemplos de Ajax.

Comment: si por ejemplo como puedes observar, las opciones de select son numericas, porque seria como la cantidad que quiero poner en mi carrito de compras, y asi sacar un calculo, cuanto seria el total dependiendo la cantidad

Comment: No entiendo bien tu comentario. Sea como sea, tú puedes enviar cualquier elemento de tu formulario, o todos los elementos de tu formulario al servidor vía Ajax para que el servidor trabaje con esa información de la forma en que lo necesite. Aquí mismo si buscas `Ajax` encontrarás muchas respuestas con explicaciones sobre cómo funciona Ajax en combinación con el servidor. O sea, Ajax es como un puente de comunicación para enviar/recibir datos entre ambos lados, justo lo que necesitas.